# How to accelerate reading elements from a C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, c, memory

I need to loop a big array, 2 Million elements, many many times.
The structure of my code looks like:

```
loop_tag= 0;

// the ig1, ig2 loop will run many times, 
// and N & M are about 30000
for(ig1=0; ig1<N; ig1++)
{   
   for(ig2=0; ig2<M; ig2++) 
   {
       
       for(k=0;k<45;k++)
       {
          element_val = arr[loop_tag];
          loop_tag ++;
          // there're a few lines to calculate something
       }
       if(loop_tag == the end of arr){loop_tag=0;}       
   }
}
```

I will run the code more than 100 000 times, each time takes me about 200~1000 sec. Actually, I have used MPI to save time. But it still needs about 10 hours with 300 CPUs being used.
I find that most of the time is spent on "element_val = arr[loop_tag];". If I just assign a value to element_val like "element_val = 0.01", the time of each running will be just about 30% of before.
How can I accelerate this part? Thanks!

Here are some outputs in the log file:

```
expo pair: 0-0-0(20193) <-> 1-0-1(22275)
Finish in 1017.22 sec. 4.49795e+08 pairs. Expo pairs got now: 1
Now 0 buffers, 1 block in current buffer

expo pair: 23-5-2(18259) <-> 201-18-1(9704)
Finish in 70.86 sec. 3.17283e+07 pairs. Expo pairs got now: 2
Now 0 buffers, 2 block in current buffer

expo pair: 23-5-2(18259) <-> 559-47-1(15243)
Finish in 608.50 sec. 2.78322e+08 pairs. Expo pairs got now: 3
Now 0 buffers, 3 block in current buffer
```

Here is the code inside the ig1- &ig2-loop. The code reads data from two exposure files each time, then it loop the lines of them. I put all the data, arrays, in the structure, expo_info.

```
// if two galaxies come from the same CFHTLenS exposure, break
if(expo_info->obs_expo_label_1[ig1] == expo_info->obs_expo_label_2[ig2]){break;}

n = ig2*expo_info->expo_data_col;

ra_z2 = expo_info->expo_data[expo_label_1][n+expo_info->ra_idx];
dec_z2 = expo_info->expo_data[expo_label_1][n+expo_info->dec_idx];
cos_dec_z2 = expo_info->expo_data[expo_label_1][n+expo_info->cos_dec_idx];

// the seperation angle (arc minute)
delta_ra = (ra_z2 - ra_z1)*cos_dec_z1;
delta_dec = dec_z2 - dec_z1;
delta_radius = sqrt(delta_ra*delta_ra + delta_dec*delta_dec);

theta_tag = -1;
for(ir=0; ir<expo_info->theta_bin_num; ir++)
{
    if(delta_radius > expo_info->theta_bin[ir] and delta_radius <= expo_info->theta_bin[ir+1]){theta_tag=ir;break;}
}
if(theta_tag > -1)
{   
    pairs+= 1;
    // shear estimators rotation (position angle defined as East of North)
    sin_theta = delta_ra/delta_radius;
    cos_theta = delta_dec/delta_radius;

    sin_2theta = 2*sin_theta*cos_theta;
    cos_2theta = cos_theta*cos_theta - sin_theta*sin_theta;

    sin_4theta = 2*sin_2theta*cos_2theta;
    cos_4theta = cos_2theta*cos_2theta - sin_2theta*sin_2theta;


    mg1_z2 = expo_info->expo_data[expo_label_1][n+expo_info->mg1_idx]*cos_2theta - expo_info->expo_data[expo_label_1][n+expo_info->mg2_idx]*sin_2theta;
    mg2_z2 = expo_info->expo_data[expo_label_1][n+expo_info->mg1_idx]*sin_2theta + expo_info->expo_data[expo_label_1][n+expo_info->mg2_idx]*cos_2theta;

    mnu1_z2 = expo_info->expo_data[expo_label_1][n+expo_info->mu_idx]*cos_4theta -expo_info->expo_data[expo_label_1][n+expo_infomv_idx]*sin_4theta;
    mnu2_z2 = mnu1_z2;

    mnu1_z2 = expo_info->expo_data[expo_label_1][n+expo_info->mn_idx] + mnu2_z2;
    mnu2_z2 = expo_info->expo_data[expo_label_1][n+expo_info->mn_idx] - mnu2_z2;
                
    // there're zbin_num *zbin_num blocks, iz1 is row, iz2 is the col, each block
    // has a length of mg_bin_num*mg_bin_num*chi_guess_num*theta_bin_num.
    iz2 = expo_info->expo_zbin_label[expo_label_1][ig2];

    ////////////////////// the key part of PDF_SYM //////////////////////////////
    ic_len = theta_tag*ir_chi_block_len + (iz1 + iz2)*expo_info-iz_chi_block_len;

    gg_1 = expo_info->gg_1[loop_label];
    gg_2 = expo_info->gg_2[loop_label];

    temp_tt[2] = mg1_z1 - gg_1*mnu1_z1;
    temp_tt[3] = mg1_z2 - gg_2*mnu1_z2;
    hist_2d_new(temp_tt[2], temp_tt[3], expo_info->mg_bin, 
    mg_bin_num,mg_bin_num1, mg_bin_num2, mg_bin_num3, ix_tt, iy_tt);
    expo_info->expo_num_count_chit[ic_len + iy_tt*mg_bin_num+ix_tt] += 1;
                
    temp_xx[2] = mg2_z1 - gg_1*mnu2_z1;
    temp_xx[3] = mg2_z2 - gg_2*mnu2_z2;

    hist_2d_new(temp_xx[2], temp_xx[3],  expo_info->mg_bin, 
    mg_bin_num,mg_bin_num1, mg_bin_num2, mg_bin_num3, ix_xx, iy_xx);
    expo_info->expo_num_count_chix[ic_len + iy_xx*mg_bin_num+ix_xx] += 1;
    loop_label += 1;


    for(ic=1; ic<chi_guess_num; ic++)
    {   
        ic_len += chi_block_len;

        // these two lines, gg_1 & gg_2, take a lot of time.
        // expo_info->gg_1 & gg_2 are two big arrays, 2 Million elements
        // if I just use something like gg_1 = 0.001; gg_2 == 0.001,
        // it runs very fast
        gg_1 = expo_info->gg_1[loop_label];
        gg_2 = expo_info->gg_2[loop_label];

        bin_para_tt[0] = ix_tt;
        bin_para_tt[1] = iy_tt;

        temp_tt[0] = temp_tt[2];
        temp_tt[1] = temp_tt[3];

        temp_tt[2] = mg1_z1 - gg_1*mnu1_z1;
        temp_tt[3] = mg1_z2 - gg_2*mnu1_z2;

        hist_2d_new(expo_info->mg_bin, mg_bin_num, temp_tt, bin_para_tt, ix_tt, iy_tt);

        expo_info->expo_num_count_chit[ic_len + iy_tt*mg_bin_num+ix_tt] += 1;
                    
        bin_para_xx[0] = ix_xx;
        bin_para_xx[1] = iy_xx;
                    
        temp_xx[0] = temp_xx[2];
        temp_xx[1] = temp_xx[3];

        temp_xx[2] = mg2_z1 - gg_1*mnu2_z1;
        temp_xx[3] = mg2_z2 - gg_2*mnu2_z2;

        hist_2d_new(expo_info->mg_bin, mg_bin_num, temp_xx, bin_para_xx, ix_xx, iy_xx);
        expo_info->expo_num_count_chix[ic_len + iy_xx*mg_bin_num+ix_xx] += 1;
        loop_label += 1;
    }
    if(loop_label >= gg_len){loop_label = 0;}
  ////////////////////// the key part of PDF_SYM -end //////////////////////////////
}
```

I find most of the time is spent on

```
gg_1 = expo_info->gg_1[loop_label];
gg_2 = expo_info->gg_2[loop_label];
```

Comment: Assuming that your algorithm is fine and you really have to loop that many times, I think introducing more parallelism would benefit you. Also, the operations seem to be very similar which should make this a good example where outsourcing the load to a GPU could yield a nice speed-up (GPGPU programming).

Comment: You can't, really accelerate memory access.  When assigning a constant value, the same memory is being accessed over and over, and that may even be optimized further by the compiler. in the code not shown ... You are hitting lots of memory cache misses because of the large data set.  These take time.  You can try using AVX to parallelize the code not shown, for really good speed gains.  Possibility depends on the calculation itself.

Comment: Also what is the type of `arr`? If its a simple integer array thats fine, if its something more complex then looking into how well your copy constructor runs is would be useful. Also you dont seem to do anything with it. Please post some fuller code.

Comment: I suspect your profiling is wrong/misleading. There's no way that reading 2 million values takes 200~1000 seconds, even if it would be a random access. A linear access like this should be prefetched.

Comment: `with 300 CPUs being used` You have access to a system with 300 CPUs?

Comment: @Thomas D. Thanks! But I am not familiar with GPU coding. I run this code on the cluster. Since there're much more CPU nodes on the cluster, it's easier to specify more CPU node than the GPU one.  10 hours is ok for the current stage.

Comment: @Michaël Roy It is hard to using AVX, because the calculation is a bit complicated. I am calculating the correlation function using the catalog.

Comment: @eerorika Yes, I'm using the cluster of the our school. There're many nodes which contains 72 cores.

Comment: @Mike Vine arr is a double array.  The code is for the correlation in astronomy. I'm not sure that post some fuller code will be helpful.

Comment: Without information about "few lines to calculate something", it is hard to see how we can help you optimize something that does 30,000 * 30,000 * 45 = 40 billion memory accesses.

Comment: @Hk_Lee  You'd be surprised.  Correlation  is a very common operation, that optimizes with amazing results with avx  I'm sure someone around here will gladly help you sort it out.  Many people here are looking for harder problems to solve than the much too common first year students' exercises :)  I imagine your 300 cpu compputer supports avx512.  You should mention that as well in the question, if you know, and/or the CPU model.

Comment: ... and the compiler.

Comment: From a quick inspection of your code, it appears that you can parallelize the outer loop entirely.  I don't see anything where the results of any calculations carry over from one loop iteration to the next, although that does depend on what `loop_label` actually is used for.

Comment: @Michaël Roy I have posted the calculation part here.  I use gcc 4.8.5. I have added the "-O1" tag to compile the file, and the code runs 2x faster. The time spent on exposure file pair is shown here now, it's about a few hundreds to one thousand seconds.

Comment: @Botje I have posted the code here.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Actually, I parallelize the exposure pairs. I build a list of all tasks, a list of many exposure pairs, and then parallelize the list.

Comment: Since the `gg_1`and `gg_2` arrays inside `expo_info` are arrays of several million elements you will be running into lots of cache misses since the two arrays will never be on the same cache line. Your best bet would be to restructure the data so that the corresponding elements of both are close to each other in memory (e.g.: having a struct with all the data that belongs together)

Comment: You should compile your code with -O2 or even -O3 before even talking about performance. Also, please check if a modern compiler will produce faster code, GCC 4.8.5 is pretty old. Or even a different compiler such as Clang or ICC (if you have a license for it).

Comment: From the gallery of stupid memory tricks: create a temporary `double[8]` where you interleave elements from gg_1 and gg_2. That has the potential to reduce your cache misses by a factor of 4. (8 elements because 64 bytes is a common cache line size)

Comment: You're doing quite a bit of floating-point operations with `double`.  You may be able to move a lot of those calculations out of the loop.  I'd also look at https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath to see what floating point optimizations you can use and still get good results. I'd at least try `-ffast-math` and see if the results are good enough.  And `sqrt(delta_ra*delta_ra + delta_dec*delta_dec)` can be replaced with `hypot(delta_ra, delta_dec)`.  That may or may not be faster.

Comment: Would you be able to post a full compilable [MCVE] (including some `main()` and relevant `#include`)? You posted some code that uses some variables - how are these variables defined? `I find most of the time is spent on` How did you "find" it? How do you exactly measure the "time"?

Comment: " for(k=0;k<45;k++) {  element_val = arr[loop_tag];  loop_tag ++; }"  This reading can be fasten by employing a struct consistent of an array of 45 doubles (I assume type of arr is double). Then use std::copy_n copy 45 double memory to the struct. The memory copy is much faster than element assignment, and is very often used in large matrix copy.